# Importing two libraries of the same name into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I imported sherlock action bar in my workspace by File>Import>Existing Android Code Into Workspace and in package explorer it is viewed with name library above my project. I also want to use this project in my app: https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview And I just can't get them both at the same time because when I try to import second library eclipse tells me that "projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the second project's code - change the package names, and import again.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change package names. As they are both different libraries, probably they already have different names. So just rename the Library project and you're good to go.