# Importing two libraries with the same name

Tags: android, eclipse

am trying to import multiple different libraries in ADT/Eclipse, but they share the same project name, how to solve this issue please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing two libraries of the same name into eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060094/importing-two-libraries-of-the-same-name-into-eclipse)

Comment: Saw that one, didn't really help me out

Answer (score -2):

I fixed this issue by renaming the first project to something else.